# Create hyperlink for URL contained in tweet text

Tags: jquery, html, node.js

I am totally new to coding. Please help. I am obtaining tweet text using node.js and displaying using html. I want to create hyperlink for URL contained in it.

for ex: #Times #News Ukrainians, Awaiting International Action After Crash, Fear Complacency http://t.co/YjZ4YV8qMk

This is the text I obtain. These are without hyperlink.When i click on #Times or http://t.co/YjZ4YV8qMk it should open on new page. Here is my html with jquery.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>  
    </head>

    <body>
        <form>
           #<input type="text" id="tag" class="hash"/> 
           <button>submit</button>
        </form>

        <div id="tweets"></div>


        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.js"></script>
         <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"> </script>

        <script>
            var socket = io.connect('/link');

            $('.hash').change(function(){
                $('#tweet').after();
                socket.emit('message', $('#tag').val()); 
                $('#tag').val('');

                return;

            });

            socket.on('message', function(msg){
                $('#tweets').after($('<div>').text(msg));
            });
        </script>
    </body>
<html>
```

Answer (score 0):

`Mistake 1`: you include two jquery library files

`Mistake 2`: Jquery library order be wrong it is always be on top of other scripts

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"> </script>
```